# Boolean expression for a modified Queens problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, boolean-algebra, binary

I saw the boolean expressions for the N Queens problem from [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Eisil/cs389L/bdd.pdf).

My modified N queens rules are simpler:

For a p $\times$ p chessboard I want to place N queens in such a way so that

1. Queens will be placed adjacently, rows will be filled first.
2. p $\times$ p chessboard size will be adjusted until it can hold N queens

For example, say N = $17$, then we need a $5\times5$ chessboard and the placement will be:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
Q &Q &Q &Q &Q \\ \hline
Q &Q &Q &Q &Q \\ \hline
Q &Q &Q &Q &Q \\ \hline
Q &Q & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
\end{array}

How would you build a boolean expression for this problem?

Comment: So the problem is "find the smallest integer $p$ such that $p^2\ge N$". What is the purpose of a boolean formulation of the problem?

Comment: Representation of the boolean formulation through Binary Decision Diagram,BDD.